# Elasticsearch reindex - unknown_host_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to reindex from a remote server.
Elasticsearch instance on the remote server is behind a nginx proxy and its url is api.example.com/api/elasticsearch on port 80.

I'm able to access the remote elasticsearch and perform queries. E.g.

```
curl http://api.example.com:80/api/elasticsearch/_cat/indices?v
```

gives the expected result.

However when I try to reindex a local elasticsearch index from the remote index as follows

```
curl -X POST http://elasticsearch:9200/_reindex -d '{ 
    "source": {
        "remote": { 
            "host": "http://api.example.com/api/elasticsearch:80"
        }, 
        "index": "alias_name" 
    }, 
    "dest": { 
        "index": "index_name" 
    }
}'
```

I receive an error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"unknown_host_exception","reason":"api.example.com/api/elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}],"type":"unknown_host_exception","reason":"api.example.com/api/elasticsearch: Name or service not known"},"status":500}
```

Comment: In the first example the address string is "http://api.example.com:80/api/elasticsearch/", in  the second one is "http://api.example.com/api/elasticsearch:80". Why you have changed the position of the port in the address string?

Comment: When I use http://api.example.com:80/api/elasticsearch as host in the reindex query I receive this error:  [host] must be of the form [scheme]://[host]:[port] but was [http://api.example.com:80/api/elasticsearch]

Comment: I had this exact same issue. My workaround was to introduce another `nginx` proxy between them that listened on an explicit port and forwarded calls. Pretty silly that this was necessary but it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

According documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html:

> The host parameter must contain a scheme, host, port (e.g.
>   https://otherhost:9200) and optional path (e.g.
>   https://otherhost:9200/proxy). The username and password parameters
>   are optional, and when they are present _reindex will connect to the
>   remote Elasticsearch node using basic auth. Be sure to use https when
>   using basic auth or the password will be sent in plain text.

In your case: "http://api.example.com:80/api/elasticsearch" or "http://api.example.com/api/elasticsearch"

Also, most important:

> Remote hosts have to be explicitly whitelisted in elasticsearch.yaml
>   using the reindex.remote.whitelist property. It can be set to a comma
>   delimited list of allowed remote host and port combinations (e.g.
>   otherhost:9200, another:9200, 127.0.10.*:9200, localhost:*)